# Assign to a file a progressive number according to time

Tags: time, batch-file

There is a way to assign to a file, lets call it abc.txt, a progressive number, that I suppose should come from the time set?

So that the name of the file could become for example abc_5367879938763.txt

Comment: What's the context? What language? This question is not answerable right now.

Comment: Yes you are right, with windows batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the string set file=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%

that gives a string of 8 characters, for example: 17360720